# Couldn't find Order with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopping-cart

I did shut down my browser but still rendering, local host server restarted but error remains.

```css
module ApplicationHelper
    def current_order
        if session[:order_id].nil?
            Order.find(session[:order_id])
        else
            Order.new
        end
    end
end
```

```html
class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @order = current_order
        @order_item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)
        @order.save
        session[:order_id] = @order.id
    end

    def update
        @order = current_order
        @order_item = @order.order_item.find(params[:id])
        @order_item.update(order_item_params)
        @order_items = @order.order_items

    end
    def destroy
        @order = current_order
        @order_item = @order.order_item.find(params[:id])
        @order_item.destroy
        @order_items = @order.order_items
    end
private
    def order_item_params
        param.require(:order_item).permit(:product_id, :p_quantity)
    end
end
```

Where i'm doing mistake..?

```
get '/products' => 'products#home'
  resources :products
  resources :order_items
  resources :carts, only: [:show]
  root 'products#home'
```

i created an order through rails console but error still rendering..#help
any detailed answer..?

Comment: can you share your `routes.rb` and at which line you are getting error?

Comment: Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/products' => 'products#home'
  resources :products
  resources :order_items
  resources :carts, only: [:show]
  root 'products#home'
end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with `current_order` method , you are passing `nil` value to find method `Order.find(nil)`. You need to swap `if` and `else` statements like this

```
def current_order
  if session[:order_id].nil?
    Order.new
  else
    Order.find(session[:order_id])   
  end
end
```